# How can I make my user-compiled app show it's logo and name in the Unity Launcher (sidebar)?

Tags: gnome, unity, compiling, launcher

I have compiled [mupdf](https://mupdf.com/index.html) from source after following the instructions on their website.

[image: This is what it looks like when the app is open.]

This is what it looks like when it's open. The program already shows up in the Unity Dash with logo, due to me manually creating the .desktop file and putting it in `usr/share/applications`. I would like to know how make it also display properly in the Launcher sidebar.

[image: my dash]

Here's how it looks in my Dash, amongst my other apps

Comment: Just to confirm, does it appear in the dash, but not in the launcher? Also, did you try rebooting?

Comment: Yes, it appears correctly in the Dash, but not in the Launcher. I actually compiled this months ago and have had many reboots since then. Could it be that mupdf came with two versions: an X11 and an opengl one? When I click mupdf in the Dash it shows up as `mupdf-gl` in the System Monitor. Maybe Unity's Launcher doesn't recognize the opengl binary as mupdf

Answer (score 0):

Make a .desktop file. Edit the `Exec` and the `Icon` entries, and add the paths for the binary launcher of mupdf, and its icon.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=MuPDF
Comment= MuPDF is a lightweight PDF, XPS, and E-book viewer. 
Exec=/path/to/the/binary/you/compiled
Icon=/path/to/your/favorite/icon.extension
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

Save it as `mupdf.desktop` in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

Finally, mark it as executable with `chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/applications/mupdf.desktop`.

Comment: I already did this, I said it in my inital post "The program already shows up in the Unity Dash with logo, due to me manually adding it there." Is it because it invokes mupdf-gl? It came with an X11 version and an opengl version